Reverse Proxy with Apache for Node.js
I've been trying for hours (unsuccessfully) to get a reverse proxy via Apache for my Node.js application. The application is Send https://gitlab.com/timvisee/send I am almost at the end of my rope, the proxy works, but always shows me only an almost empty application. https://ibb.co/8MNTZm0
This is my Apache configuration The one for port 80 just forwards
  GNU nano 7.2                   send.furrysend.de-le-ssl.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName send.furrysend.de

ProxyPass / http://185.216.179.27:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://185.216.179.27:8080
ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/send.furrysend.de/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/send.furrysend.de/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

I would be very happy about help, I strongly think that it is only due to certain switches in the settings.
The IP address can be used to see what it should look like http://185.216.179.27:8080/ address is already redirected
I had already tried nginx without success
I have already tried every conceivable switch without success.
I just don't understand why it doesn't work
apache error log

[Sat May 25 00:00:26.473069 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4390:tid 140081991391104] AH00489: Apache/2.4.59 (Debian) OpenSSL/3.0.11 configured -- >
[Sat May 25 00:00:26.473134 2024] [core:notice] [pid 4390:tid 140081991391104] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat May 25 01:06:22.616820 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081750791872] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 152.89.198.175:41760] A>
[Sat May 25 01:06:22.854293 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081834718912] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 152.89.198.175:41768] A>
[Sat May 25 01:06:47.148130 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081817933504] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 52.76.71.100:1228] AH00>
[Sat May 25 01:06:48.099864 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081784362688] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 52.76.71.100:46536] AH0>
[Sat May 25 01:06:49.048600 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081767577280] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 52.76.71.100:59733] AH0>
[Sat May 25 01:06:50.003296 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081851504320] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 52.76.71.100:64279] AH0>
[Sat May 25 01:06:50.950113 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081742399168] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 52.76.71.100:48839] AH0>
[Sat May 25 01:09:14.612828 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081725613760] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 203.55.81.13:54266] AH0>
[Sat May 25 01:09:15.589433 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081717221056] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 203.55.81.13:54254] AH0>
[Sat May 25 02:22:57.937057 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081792755392] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 149.50.110.239:46090] A>
[Sat May 25 02:37:44.536095 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081784362688] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 203.55.81.13:44548] AH0>
[Sat May 25 02:37:46.241278 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081775969984] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 203.55.81.13:44556] AH0>
[Sat May 25 03:33:14.156521 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081742399168] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 103.228.37.56:48492] AH>
[Sat May 25 03:46:22.252391 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081717221056] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 203.55.81.13:36040] AH0>
[Sat May 25 03:46:22.252381 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081885075136] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 203.55.81.13:36052] AH0>
[Sat May 25 03:53:18.408023 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081859897024] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): >
[Sat May 25 03:53:18.408161 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081859897024] [client 87.121.69.52:57962] AH00898: Error reading from remote se>
[Sat May 25 04:05:17.923588 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081801148096] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 115.231.78.12:9484] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:05:18.336876 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081792755392] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 115.231.78.12:35401] AH>
[Sat May 25 04:05:19.281043 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081826326208] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 115.231.78.12:58458] AH>
[Sat May 25 04:05:20.706212 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081775969984] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 115.231.78.12:15059] AH>
[Sat May 25 04:05:21.126566 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081843111616] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 115.231.78.12:59105] AH>
[Sat May 25 04:05:21.893835 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081851504320] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 115.231.78.12:32734] AH>
[Sat May 25 04:05:22.687431 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081759184576] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 115.231.78.12:30853] AH>
[Sat May 25 04:06:31.000079 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081885075136] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): >
[Sat May 25 04:06:31.000311 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081885075136] [client 82.197.67.219:42124] AH00898: Error reading from remote s>
[Sat May 25 04:15:27.429034 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081725613760] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 84.54.51.37:48676] AH00>
[Sat May 25 04:37:51.110362 2024] [core:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081834718912] [client 111.20.182.26:2568] AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%>
[Sat May 25 04:37:51.598528 2024] [core:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081817933504] [client 111.20.182.26:2569] AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/%%>
[Sat May 25 04:37:52.098438 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081784362688] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2570] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:54.637177 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081801148096] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2571] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:55.021555 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081767577280] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2572] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:55.534621 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081717221056] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2573] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:56.062104 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081792755392] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2574] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:56.447541 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081734006464] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2575] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:56.827711 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081700435648] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2576] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:57.443045 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081876682432] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2577] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:57.825470 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081901860544] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2578] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:58.180891 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081809540800] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2579] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:59.559212 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081750791872] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2580] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:37:59.924890 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081893467840] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2581] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:38:00.421779 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081868289728] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2582] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:38:00.944956 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13981:tid 140081859897024] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2583] AH0>
[Sat May 25 04:38:01.317814 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 13982:tid 140081700435648] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 111.20.182.26:2584] AH0>


Seems like your conf file has no effect at all. Make sure that no other config  covers that server name. First active config (alphabetic order) that matches will be applied. Might be some default-ssl.conf for example.
What does apaches error log say about the 500's?

no i have deactivated the standard page, there are only the two pages under sites-enabled
I have attached the log above

If the proxy start url has a trailing slash, your target url also needs a trailing slash
As your proxy is on the public/main directory & not a sub-directory (Just /) it in itself is a trailing slash. Therefore you need to add trailing slash to the target url too:
ProxyPass / http://185.216.179.27:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://185.216.179.27:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost On

I replicated the same issue on my side & tested the above to confirm it works. The output after adding trailing slashes:
Output with trailing slashes

Thank you so much.
I knew it was just a small switch, but unfortunately the solution was beyond my knowledge. thank you for even recreating the problem!
